# Swift check type against a generic type

Tags: swift

I've a generic function with 1 parameter and want to check the type of the passed parameter with the generic type. Something like this:

```
func generic<T>(parameter: AnyObject) -> Bool {
    if parameter is T {
        return true
    } else {
        return false
    }
}
```

But I don't know how to call this

```
generic<String>("Hello")
```

Gives me a compiler error: "Cannot explicitly specialize a generic function
generic("Hello")

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You cannot tell a function what the types of its generic placeholders are (unlike with a generic struct).  It must infer them from the context e.g. its arguments.

One way to do what you want is to add another argument related to type `T`.  Rather than pass in a dummy value, you could use the metatype of the type you want:

```
func generic<T>(parameter: AnyObject, type: T.Type) -> Bool {
    if parameter is T {
        return true
    } else {
        return false
    }
}

let o: AnyObject = "hello"
generic(o, String.self)    // true
generic(o, NSString.self)  // also true
generic(o, Int.self)       // false
```

However, I would ask you, what is it you think you're achieving here?  You've essentially done nothing more than implement `is` as a function:

```
o is String     // true
o is NSString   // true
o is Int        // false
```

The point of generics is to operate on arguments generically, but you aren't giving the function any argument of a specific type to actually do any work on (hence the inability to infer one).

Comment: I've a more complex scenario. I just simplified the problem I have.

Comment: I posit that you've simplified it to the point where it's clear it doesn't make sense to do what you're doing.

Comment: ^ I needed to access the dynamic type name T.self correctly inside a generic function for getting correct entity names (core data) instead of the abstract entity name (doesn't exist) where <T: AbstractEntity>.

This approach worked for me

Answer (score 28):

Checking if generic type is which class.

```
protocol Some {}
class SomeClass: Some {}
class AClass: Some {}
func test(_ t: T) -> String {
    if T.self == SomeClass.self {
        return "Some Class"
    } else {
        return "Another Class"
    }
}

print(test(SomeClass())) // Some Class
print(test(AClass())) // Another Class
```

Answer (score 3):

This situation is not a candidate for a generic. You are just asking to test an object against a type. If this is always going to be an AnyObject, you might try something like this:

```
func istest(parameter: AnyObject, whattype: AnyObject.Type) -> Bool {
    if parameter.dynamicType === whattype.self {
        return true
    } else {
        return false
    }
}
```

If you really want a generic that you can specialize, you cannot specialize a function explicitly, so you will have to wrap your function in a generic type and specialize that:

```
struct Generic<T> {
    func generic(parameter: AnyObject) -> Bool {
        if parameter is T {
            return true
        } else {
            return false
        }
    }
}

let ok = Generic<String>().generic("howdy")
let ok2 = Generic<Int>().generic(1)
```

But the example you have given, as I've already said, is not a good candidate for doing that. Remember, a generic is resolved at compile time - we already know what the resolved type is going to be. Thus, your test is pointless because you already know the answer. That is why I showed you an alternative function where the value and the type are both unknown.

Comment: `AnyObject.Type` can be written as `AnyClass`. `whattype.self` is the same as `whattype`. And `parameter.dynamicType === whattype` tests whether the object's class is exactly the given class, which is not the same meaning as `is`. For the original meaning, you can do `parameter.isKindOfClass(whattype)`.

Comment: @newacct I said "something like". I know that `is` does not give the same result as `===` but I didn't want to involve Cocoa Foundation methods directly. It's just a "serving suggestion."

Answer (score 1):

#### A more generic approach:

```
struct Asserter<T>{
    func generic(_ val:Any) -> Bool{
        let type = type(of: val)
        return T.self == type
    }
}
_ = Asserter<String>().generic(2)//false
_ = Asserter<String>().generic("")//true
```