# How to pass any class or struct as a parameter in function?

Tags: ios, swift, function, generics, swift4

I am using Swift 4.1 and Xcode 9.3. I want to make a function which takes any Class or Struct as parameter.

Code example:

```
func cast<T>(a: Any, b: T) {

    let c = a as? b

    if let c = c {
        print("Good: \(c)")
    } else {
        print("Bad")
    }

}

cast(a: 1, b: Int.self)
```

But it has error in this line:

```
let c = a as? b
```

Error: `Use of undeclared type 'b'`

I want to call function cast like this: `cast(a: 1, b: Int)` or like this: `cast(a: "a", b: String)`
The main idea to pass class or struct as parameter in generics functions correctly, how to do this?
Thank you very much for any help or advice!

Comment: Why casting, and why using a second parameter, when you can simply do `func foo<T>(a: T)`?

Comment: Thank you for response. Casting is for example, but how to pass Int as parameter?

Comment: I think casting is for checking: is it exactly Int or not.

Comment: Is it related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27746706/swift-check-type-against-a-generic-type

Comment: When you call `foo(a: 1)` you can be sure a is Int. Likewise, in `foo(a: "bar")`, a is String. No need to check.

Comment: @Gereon, no, because I can call cast like this: cast(a: "a", b: Int.self) I need to check, is "a" a type of "b"?

Comment: @Ahmad F, you are right also. Thank you too!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should cast property to the type you've passed

```
let c = a as? T
```

And if you want to pass a type to the method you should write `T.Type`

Complete code:

```
func cast<T>(a: Any, b: T.Type) {

    let c = a as? T

    if let c = c {
        print("Good: \(c)")
    } else {
        print("Bad")
    }

}
```

Usage:

```
cast(a: 1, b: Int.self)
cast(a: "a", b: String.self)
```

After run these two lines you'll see in console:

```
Good: 1
Good: a
```

Comment: This answer is exactly I was looking for, thank you! I am accepting it. Thank you very much!

Comment: By the way, I bet you know what does code: Int.self and T.Type means?

Comment: @Alex T.Type means that you must pass a type rather than a value. Int.self returns Int as type.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the answer again and for explanation!

Comment: And, I do not want to use you, but can you answer two more questions: 1. Why I can't use: let c = a as? b 2. Why I can not use like this: func cast<T>(a: Any, b: T) {
let c = a as? T.Type ...

Comment: 1. You are trying to cast property to another property. Casting must be only to some Type.

2. Because you'll need to pass some property to the method and Swift can't do cast like this :)

Comment: Ok! Thank you very much one more time!